# Integration test for springboot with initalize query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I am going use an integration test in spring boot with in memory mysql database.But my test component in repository part query like:

```
@Query(
             value = "SELECT order_id,title,description,requirement,salary,user_info.name,user_info.contact,date"+
                     " FROM job_order " +
                     " FULL JOIN user_info " +
                     " ON sender_id=user_info.id" +
                     " WHERE order_id= ?1 ;",nativeQuery = true
     )
     Response singlejob(int order_id);
```

My entrypoint is doing stuff on the job_order table.The query require two tables ,so i am trying to insert the user_info table and then test for the job_order.Then a write test like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = { SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.class })

class OrderServiceApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;



    //@Sql("INSERT INTO user_info(name) VALUES \"alex\" ")
    @Test
    @Sql("{/resources/schema.sql}")
    void shouldCreatePost() throws Exception {
        JobOrder job=jobRepository.save(createjob());
        String request=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(job);


        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/Job/Joborder")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(request))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());


    }



    JobOrder createjob(){
        JobOrder job=new JobOrder();
        job.setTitle("Hiring software engineer");
        job.setDescription("responsible for developing and maintaining mobile app");
        job.setRequirement("Need to know basic sql springboot,2 years exp");
        job.setSalary(234);
        job.setOrder_id(1);
        return job;

    }
}
```

schema.sql:
INSERT INTO user_info (name) VALUES ('India');

and i got an error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [com/example/OrderService/{/resources/schema.sql}]

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:239)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.execute(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:269)
    at org.springframewo
```

My properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

My Path:
[image]

I dont know what is the problem on my path.And i am wondering if there are problem on my test script or strategy

Answer (score 0):

Path resource semantics should be followed when `@Sql` annotation is used. If you want to load the script file from the resources folder you should use `classpath:` reference:

```java
@Sql(value = {"classpath:schema.sql"})
```

Comment: Sadly,it also cant work